# How to echo out all elements of php array at once?

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

hi friends I have a php array for eg.

```
$mob_numbers= array(12345674, 12345675, 12345676,12345677);
```

I want to eacho out all of them at once so that it  appears

`12345674,12345675,12345676,12345677` **(with comma)** .

How do i do it ? I tried array explode, didn't work. Pls help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function as:

```
echo implode(',',$mob_numbers);
```

`explode` is used to split a `string` to get an `array`

`implode` does the opposite of joining the `array` elements to get a `string`.

Comment: ... also known as `join` in other languages (in fact, PHP also has a `join()` alias for `implode()`)